# gmake shell and PATH in a Makefile

Tags: shell, path, make

Could anyone please explain why following:

```
export PATH:=$(PATH):~/bin2
B:=$(shell PATH=$(PATH) testXq.sh)
$(warning $(B))
```

Is working properly showing results of run of the ~/bin2/testXq.sh, while following:

```
export PATH:=$(PATH):~/bin2
B:=$(shell testXq.sh)
$(warning $(B))
```

Returns an error:

```
make: testXq.sh: Command not found
```

I am on gmake v4.0

Comment: related - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11530/adding-directory-to-path-through-makefile

Comment: No, I don't want to export anything to parent environment. It's not related at all.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that this is duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838715/makefile-variable-initialization-and-export

Which seems a bug in make https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?10593 .

Comment: It does not look like a bug in `gmake`. Note that this is completely non-portable stuff that regires `gmake`.

Comment: It is: 1. Bug report exist. 2. Behaviour is not documented. 3. This question about gmake, and that is clear from the title. Why you talking about portability?

Answer (score -1):

It is most unlikely that `gmake` expands the tilde character, so the tilde remains in the PATH.

The shell however later expands the tilde when the PATH string is passed to the shell again.

Besides the fact that `gmake` does not expand the tilde character, there is another problem:

- `gmake` seems to implement the `export` keyword only for "normal" shell commands that are run from rules (shell commands after a TAB inserted text).

This is not the first time when `gmake` causes problems with it's non-orthogonal implementation. Gmake e.g. claims to run on OpenVMS but the `$(shell cmd)` method does not work on OpenVMS.

Comment: No that's entirely not the case, entire PATH seems not propagated.

Comment: But with a tilde inside and that tilde gets expanded to $HOME later in the shell in case you add `PATH=$(PATH)`.

Comment: Yes, so there is totally no problem with expansion.

Comment: So you now understand my answer that explains why you need to pass the PATH= assignment to the shell?

Comment: And you seem missed, totally, that is the problem here. Observed behavior is because _any_ variable is not propagated to shell's environment automatically. If you do $(shell var=$(var) command) you just execute string in shell 'var=value_of_gmake_var command' which is interpreted by shell as 'set _var_ to _value_of_gmake_ and execute _command_', so that effectively propagation of single variable. Hope now it is clear?

Comment: Really, I naturally hate saying 'you wrong' especially to the person who trying to help you. Sorry.

Comment: OK, so you do not grok anything here :-( The shell in your first case sees something like: PATH=abc:~/bin2 and the shell of course expands a tilde in a variable assignment when it appears after a colon

Comment: I tested, you right, it does expand, but that still has no relation to the question, because if I do makefile with

    export PATH=~/bin \n
    A=$(shell env | grep PATH) \n
    $(warning $(A)) \n

It would not print path with ~. Test it, and you understand why your answer is, while holding truth about expansions, is wrong explanation of the problem. I also removed my comment that shell don't expand tilde, because it was wrong statement.

Comment: OK, it may be that gmake does not correctly "export" variables. Besides the fact that gmake does not expand the tilde character, it does not export "exported" variables to the shell.