# Is it possible to pass environment variables from child to parent in user space?

Tags: shell, process, environment-variables

As the title says, I want to be able to change environment variables
in a parent process (specifically, a shell)
from a child process (typically a script). 
From pseudo terminal `/dev/pts/id` trying to export `key=value` from child script,
so exported variables has to be passed somehow to parent, if possible?

echoing `cmd > /proc/$$/fd/0` doesn't execute `cmd`, only view command in shell terminal emulator, and of course using `$(cmd)` instead of `cmd` executes in subshell, and `export` doesn't add variables to parent process.

1. I prefer that all the work be done in the child side.
2. I was asked in comments, what am I trying to achieve? that is a general question, and I'm trying to use the positive answer to pass variables from a script executed (spawned) by a (parent) shell, so that the user can benefit from added variables without any further work. 
   For example, I would like to have a script install an application,
   and the application directory should be added in the parent shell path.

Comment: Setting an environment variable in a parent process is not possible from a child. Try adding a description of what it is you want to achieve with this to the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda edited

Comment: You can't achieve a communication between two processes (whichever their relationship might be: parent → child or not) without a mechanism on both sides: one of them to talk and the other to listen.

Comment: Anwered here for both Linux and Windows: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38205/change-environment-of-a-running-process/502129#502129 The idea is to pass into child script a temporary directory path, have save files into it and load back in a parent script using introduced help scripts.

Comment: Calling the child with the `source` command would work (to set variables in the parent), right? E.g. put `source child.sh` in your `parent.sh`. https://linuxize.com/post/bash-source-command/ It technically handles it in the scripts, not the environments, but I think it does what the OP wanted.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38205/change-environment-of-a-running-process. That answer is to change env variables in any other process, but this one is specifically for a child -> parent relationship. And if the parent calls the child in the right way (i.e. `source` as I answered above), then it should work.

Comment: I think the key issue here is that the OP is looking for a way to do this without any work on the parent side. My suggestion just asks the user of the parent to call the script differently (with `source` instead of say, `bash`), which might count as work.

Comment: In case anyone's curious why you can't force a change in the parent environment when your child script is called with `bash`, it's for security and reliability. You don't want to just any script you call to mess up your current script's functioning. If you choose to `source` a script, that requires a higher level of trust and understanding about what it does.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**No**, it's not possible

> Not without some kind of [workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38212/347236).

Environment variables can only be passed from parent to child (as part of environment export/inheritance), not the other way around.

Comment: any possible hacks?

Comment: @Error, use temporary file to store the variable

Comment: @Error `any possible hacks?` There's a nasty hack:  attach a debugger to the parent process and have it run `setenv( "ENVAL=value" );`  See the question linked in the comments above.  Something like that is great when someone thinks setting an environment variable to "read-only" in `bash` actually works.

Comment: @RomeoNinov edited

Comment: @AndrewHenle will consider that, question edited though.

Comment: Incorrect answer, it is possible: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38205/change-environment-of-a-running-process/502129#502129

Comment: @Andry No, your comment is *incorrect*. That question/answer talks about changing environment variable of a certain process while it's running, whereas this question/answer talks about passing environment variable from a child process to the parent process. These are totally orthogonal subjects.

Comment: @heemayl My answer describes exactly how to pass a variable from child shell script to parent shell script, so it can be solved that way, and yes it is posssible. All you have to do is just save a variable into described file or files. So, you answered as it is not possible, which in general is incorrect answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can transmit variables values from a child to its parent process through a file or a named pipe.

Here is a theoretical simplest example:

child process:

```
echo ${variable} >/tmp/file
```

parent process:

```
read variable </tmp/file
```

Comment: question edited

Comment: alternatively  `echo "variable=${variable}" > /tmp/file; source /tmp/file`

Answer (score 5):

This is very tricky
if the parent process is not expecting and cooperating with it. 
In that case, see [change environment of a running process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38205/80216)
and [Is there a way to change another process's environment variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/205064/3960947)

If the parent process is expecting the value
and cooperating with the transfer,
the simple way is to use command substitution:

```
export VAR=$(cmd)
```

This assumes that the value of the variable
is the *only* thing the program wants to write. 
If the child process needs to be able to write to the screen
(specifically, the parent’s stdout),
we can do that by hiding the parent’s file descriptor 1
in another file descriptor:

```
exec 3>&1       # Copy our file descriptor 1 into file descriptor 3.
                # child_prog will be invoked with file descriptor 1 pointing to a pipe
                # for the command substitution, but all other file descriptors intact.
                # Specifically, fd3 will point to our stdout.
export var=$(child_prog)
exec 3>&-       # (Optionally) close fd3 as cleanup.
```

Now, if `child_prog` is short and simple,
it may be easiest simply to write the value for the variable
to file descriptor 1
and use file descriptor 3 (`cmd >&3`)
as the standard output. 
If it’s large and/or complex, you’ll want to do something like:

```
exec 5>&1       # Redirect fd1 (the command substitution pipe) to fd5.
exec 1>&3       # Set our fd1 (stdout) to our parent's stdout (which was passed in as fd3).
exec 3>&-       # Close fd3; it’s no longer needed.
```

and then use stdout normally, and use `>&5` for writing the value.

So far I’ve been assuming that
you want to pass only one value to one variable. 
If you have multiple values,
it’s a simple matter of delimiting them with a character (or string)
that’s guaranteed not to appear in any of the values. 
If we select `@@`, then the parent can say

```
exec 3>&1
temp=$(child_prog)
exec 3>&-
export var1="${temp%%@@*}"
rest="${temp#*@@}"
export var2="${rest%%@@*}"
export var3="${rest#*@@}"
```

and the child can say
`echo "value1@@value2@@value3" >&5`.

If it’s hard to find a string of printing characters
that’s guaranteed not to appear in any of the values, you can use newline. 
Just change `@@` to newline in the above commands:

Parent:

```
export var1="${temp%%
*}"
rest="${temp#*
}"
export var2="${rest%%
*}"
export var3="${rest#*
}"
```

Child:

```
printf "%s\n" "value1" "value2" "value3" >&5
```

---

Yet another variation is to have the child feed *commands*
back to the parent, rather than values. 
If the parent says `. <(child_prog)`,
it runs the child, captures the output, *and executes it*. 
Then the child can do

```
printf "export var1='value1'\nexport var2='value2' var3=\"value3\"\n" >&5
```

(I tested this with a *`value3`* that contained an apostrophe,
so I had to quote it with `\"…\"`,
and I left it that way just to illustrate the alternative syntax.)

A feature of this technique is that you can add variable(s)
to be exported without changing the code in the parent.

This approach requires that the parent process be running bash
(or maybe one of the other advanced shells?),
since POSIX doesn’t support `<(cmd)`.

Comment: you could use `eval` as well

Comment: @hbogert: And you ***could*** fly a kite during a thunderstorm, but why would you want to? Seriously, can you describe a realistic, practical example of something you could do with `eval` that you can’t do with my answer as written?  `eval` is like a chainsaw; it is good for some things, but you should think long and hard before you use it.

Comment: Yes, as you said, `<()` is a bash feature, so in the case you are not running Bash, you can resort to eval. Further, sourcing a dynamically generated script is pretty much eval.

Comment: Hey, how do you know that `child_prog` will be invoked with file descriptor 1 pointing to a pipe?

Comment: @clapas:  Well, technically, I don’t.  But what, exactly, are you asking?  Do you understand [Command Substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)?

Comment: Nevermind. I found out myself with this command: `echo "$(ls -l /proc/self/fd)"`. I can see fd `1` points to a pipe.