# arithmetic operation inside Makefile rules

Tags: bash, make, arithmetic

I need to perform an arithmetic operation inside a bash loop as explained below

```
CYCLE?=3
COUNT=1

download_when_ready: ## Will try the download operations many times till it succeeds or it reaches 10 tries
    while ! composer update $(bundle) 2> /dev/null && [[ $(COUNT) -lt 10 ]]; \
    do \
        COUNT=$$(( $(COUNT)+1 )); \
        SLEEP=$$(( ($(COUNT) / $(CYCLE)) + ($(COUNT) % $(CYCLE)) )); \
        echo "count $(COUNT)"; \
        echo "cycle $(CYCLE)"; \
        echo "sleep $(SLEEP)"; \
        sleep $(SLEEP); \
    done
```

This never stops and gives the following:

```
count 0
cycle 4
sleep 0

count 0
cycle 4
sleep 0

....

count 0
cycle 4
sleep 0
```

As you can see, variables have the initial values and never change !

**UPDATE**

> PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4"

However the following code keeps the value of `$$c` empty, before the while loop and inside it.

```
CYCLE?=3
COUNT=1

download_when_ready: ## Will try the download operations many times till it succeeds or it reaches 10 tries
    @c=$(COUNT);
    @echo $$c;
    while ! composer update $(bundle) 2> /dev/null && [[ $(COUNT) -lt 10 ]]; \
    do \
        echo "$$c"; \
    done
```

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11530/117549

Comment: Looks like you're mixing up Makefile variables and shell variables...

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry but where did I use shell variables?

Comment: @smarber Exactly. Shell code can only change shell variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [@Kusalananda comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419815/arithmetic-operation-inside-makefile-rules#comment754535_419815), I figured it out.

I used [make](/questions/tagged/make) variable as initial values for [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) variables

```
CYCLE?=3
COUNT=1

download_when_ready: ## Will try the download operations many times till it succeeds or it reaches 10 tries
    while ! composer update $(bundle) 2> /dev/null && [ "$$c" -lt 10 ]; \
    do \
        c=$$(( $${c:-$(COUNT)}+1 )); \
        s=$$(( ($$c / $(CYCLE)) + ($$c % $(CYCLE)) )); \
        echo "count $$c"; \
        echo "cycle $(CYCLE)"; \
        echo "sleep $$s"; \
        sleep $$s; \
    done
```

And this does work!

```
count 1
cycle 4
sleep 1
count 2
cycle 4
sleep 2
count 3
cycle 4
sleep 3
count 4
```

Thanks to [@Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) & [@Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas)

Comment: `[[ $(COUNT) -lt 10 ]]` will be expanded by make to `[[ 1 -lt 10 ]]` before calling `sh`. So that tell will always be true. Also note that `[[...]]` is not `sh` syntax.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas True! fixed now thanks! Yeah `[[ ... ]]` must be `bash` I assume, and that's fine for me... Thanks again!

Comment: `[[...]]` is ksh syntax, also supported by `bash` and `zsh`. It's not in `sh`. If you want to use that, you should set the `SHELL` _make_ variable (which is independant from the SHELL environment variable) to a shell that supports that non-standard syntax. But note that not all systems have bash installed and those that do don't have it always in the same place (can be /usr/gnu/bin/bash, /usr/local/bin/ash, /opt/gnu/bin/bash... depending on the system). Just use `[ "$$c" -lt 10 ]` and you won't have to require bash/ksh/zsh

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I prefer this syntax `[ $${c:-0} -lt 10 ]`, is it standard ?

Comment: @smarber, yep (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 ). Though you could just begin the script with `c=$(COUNT)` and you wouldn't need the default value

Comment: @smarter, yes, that's standard but that's still not what you want to do, that would still potentially call `[` with a value of `$c` that is taken from the environment. It's very dangerous to use uninitialised shell variables in arithmetic contexts. Here, you'd want to initiallise the `c` shell variable from the COUNT make variable before ever expanding/using it: `c=$(COUNT); while ...`

Comment: I don't know why but with `c=$(COUNT); while ...` the variable `c` does not get set with `$(COUNT)` value... @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: Works for me with a rule that does `c=$(COUNT); echo $$c`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it does not work for me, I updated my question

Comment: You need the backslash at the end of `c=$(COUNT)`. Otherwise `make` runs two separate `sh` instances. That's why you have `;` at the end of your line. That's because those lines end up joined together because of the backslash.